# fill text box when select a value form drop down

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

how to fill text boxes based on drop down selection
i have a table:

```
empid  empshortname  empname empdesignation
```

when i select empshortname from drop down that should be fill the empname in one text box, empdesignation in another text box like this i want to fill in many text boxes based on single selection

Thanks and regards
sreedhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  understand that you want to take the value empshortName from the dropdown and according to it select the others properties from DB or somewhere..
so, to get the value of the selected empshortName write an event function: SelectedIndexChanged and there write:

```
    string empName=dropdown.Items[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;//to get the key value 
 or: 
    string empName=dropdown.Items[dropdown.selectedIndex].Text; //to get the display text
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going :)
http://api.jquery.com/change/